# javascript mailto:a@b.com results in 'failed to load resource' error...?

Tags: javascript, mailto

I have the following block:

```
<a href="mailto:a@b.com">Send me a mail!</a>
```

There's plenty of styles applied to the  tag, but when I click the link, I get the error:

```
Failed to load resource mailto:a@b.com
```

From my testing, this appears to ONLY work in IE... Every other browser (firefox 4, Opera 11+, Safari 5.0.4 (or something like that) and Chrome 12) all do nothing upon clicking the link...

Ideas?

Comment: The fact that the `mailto` link works in no browser suggests to me that there's something else going on here. Maybe some Javascript is interfering? Sounds like we'd need the whole document to truly work on debugging this one.

Comment: Lol, fair enough... Have a go at it cap'n... [link](http://www1.cybermed.org/website/services/training/index.html), once there, click on the 'Data Migration' option, and you'll see a 'Write to us' button...

Comment: FWIW: I get the error in Chrome, but my default email client still loads up a new email with the correct Subject and To lines.

Comment: @Thomas - I don't have a default Email client configured on my side, and I don't even get a warning about it through chrome... IE does warn me that there's no Default client configured, which is good enough... Oh, and what's FWIW?

Comment: glad you got it sorted it out. :) FWIW = "For what it's worth"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*mailto*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) pseudo protocol has been supported by pretty much every user agent. It is included in [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#fetching-resources) (more or less), so it should work everywhere. However some of its features are unreliable.

It will normally only fail if a default email client has not been assigned for the OS, or perhaps if application mappings in the user agent preferences aren't correctly set.

Comment: Yes, you are most likely correct, as the issue revolves around the default mail client not being configured.